Why does blur fire in between 2 focus events when I focus a Tab/window? [Chrome]
I am building a chrome extension and want to do foo() if the user comes back to my extension tab. My current problem is, when I click the tab of my extension:

first a focus event fires
then a blur event fires (why?)
then another focus event fires (also why)

  var focusWasAway = false;
  var counter = 0;
  window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    if (focusWasAway) {
      focusWasAway = false;
      console.log("hello", counter);
      counter = counter + 1;
      foo()
    };
  });
  window.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    console.log("blurring");
    focusWasAway = true;
  });

I would like to understand what leads to the tab loosing focus and then gaining focus again on being clicked.
visual example with console

If someone needs a solution listen to visibilitychange on the document, see here
  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
    if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
      console.log("I only fire once");
      foo()
    }
  });

However I'd still like to understand what triggers blur and focus in the given example.
